# MS Access VBA Reference

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this database and it was working perfect, but today it started hating me. I started getting a Compile error: Can't find project or library. I looked around and found that when using the front end on a different computer, under VBA and references, it was missing a reference for Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library.

My computer I have the Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library checked. How can I get this to work on other computers with 15.0 and 16.0?

Here is the code

```
Private Sub cmd_LocateFile_Click()
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
Dim sFile As String
Dim sFolder As String
Dim ID As Long
Dim sTarget As String



sFile = FSBrowse("", msoFileDialogFilePicker, "All Files (*.*),*.*")
If sFile <> "" Then
    sFolder = ("\\aiowima23fp1\Ecological Sciences and Engineering\Cultural Resources\New - Cultural Resources Request Database") & "\" & sAttachmentFolderName & "\"
    If FolderExist(sFolder) = False Then MkDir (sFolder)
    ID = RequestID_FK  ' Set current record id.
sTarget = sFolder & CStr(ID) & "-" & GetFileName(sFile)
If CopyFile(sFile, sFolder & GetFileName(sTarget)) = True Then
        Me!FullFileName.Value = sTarget
    Else
    End If
End If

Error_Handler_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Source: " & sModName & "\cmd_LocateFile_Click" & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
       Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
       , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Sub
```

Comment: Use late bindings. If you want anything more specific than that, you need to share your code.

Comment: I edited the question to include the code

Comment: Please include the code that depends on the Microsoft Word Object Library reference, not just random code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding references to Word during development has the advantage to be able to use strongly typed word objects and thus being able to take advantage of IntelliSense. But these references are, as you have experienced, sensible to versioning. Therefore, I suggest you remove the reference to Word once development is achieved. You will also have to replace all Word-related types by `Object`, i.e. use late binding. This makes the application more robust with respect to versioning.

You can get an existing Word instance which is already open or open a new one with this code snippet, without any references to Word DLLs.

```vb
Public Function GetWordApplication() As Object
    'Gets an active Word application or opens a new Word instance.
    'Raises Error No. 8 if word cannot be opened.

    On Error Resume Next
    'Find existing instance of Word
    Set GetWordApplication = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'Not found, create new instance.
        Set GetWordApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If

    'Following code is optional. You can instead test for Nothing at the call site
    On Error Goto 0
    If GetWordApplication Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise 8, "YourApp.GetWordApplication", "Word could not be opened."
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a life saver!